# Query to return first row based on condition

Tags: teradata

I would like to get the first row from the table only when the condition gets satisfied. The table has multiple entries and only when the particular value of a column is present at the top of the table, the query should return the output else the query should not return any row.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COL1 = 'AAA' THEN COL1 ELSE NULL END) AS A
FROM TABLE
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) = 1
WHERE A IS NOT NULL
```

If the value of the column is 'AAA' present at the top of the table then it should return the output, if not then no row should be returned. I am still getting the output as 'AAA' even when the first row is not 'AAA'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must move your WHERE-condition to QUALIFY:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) = 1
    AND COL1 = 'AAA'
```

Answer (score 1):

This query should get the first row from the table and see if the COL1 is equal to "AAA."

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1) WHERE COL1 = 'AAA'
```

Comment: I tried this query and it worked                                                                             
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE ORDER BY TIMESTAMP 
    DESC) A WHERE COL1 = 'AAA'                     Thanks for your help